# Classify all the Galois group of the splitting field of $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

When the ground field is $\mathbb Q$ that is trivial. But what if the ground field has positive characteristic?

Is it still true that every Galois group has order 1,2,4,8?

Comment: Don't forget that the Galois group for any finite field extension is cyclic.

Comment: @sharding4 Yes but how to compute them

Comment: How many extensions of degree 2 does any finite field have?

Comment: @sharding4 Do you mean that the extension of finite field is at most 2? I have idea now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to determine the galois group $G$ of the extension $L=K(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3, \sqrt 5)$ over *any* field $K$. A priori $G \cong(\mathbf Z/2)^n$, with $n=0, 1, 2$ or $3$, and you wish to show that all values of $n$ can occur.

1) Suppose char $(K) \neq 2$. Since $K$ contains the group $(\pm 1)$ of square roots of $1$, Kummer's theory applies and tells you that $G\cong Hom (R, (\pm 1))$, where the so called Kummer radical $R$ is the subgroup of $K^*/{K^*}^2$ generated by the classes of $2, 3, 5$ mod ${K^*}^2$. A (multiplicative) linear dependence relation reads (@) $2^a.3^b.5^c =x^2$, with $x\in K^*$ and $a, b, c \in$ {0, 1}. Then :
- if $K=\mathbf Q$, the relation (@) implies $a=b=c=0$ because $\mathbf Z$ is a UFD, so $n=3$  - take $K=\mathbf F_p$, where $p$ is an odd prime such that for instance $(\frac {5}{p})=-1$, so that $\mathbf F_p(\sqrt 5)/\mathbf F_p$ is a quadratic extension, actually the unique such extension in a fixed algebraic closure; then $L=\mathbf F_p(\sqrt 5)$ and $n=1$.

2) If char $K=2$, then $2=0$ , $3=5=1$, and $L=K$, i.e. $n=0$. See also complement (iii) below

3) If char $(K)$ is an odd prime $p$, see complement (iii) below

**Complements**. (i) If char$(K)=2$, when dealing with quadratic  (not necessarily quadratic radical) extensions, one can apply Artin-Schreier's theory instead of Kummer's

(ii) Let $K=\mathbf F_q$, with $q$ = a power of an odd prime $p$. Since ${\mathbf F_q}^*$ is cyclic, it admits a unique subgroup of index $2$, which is no other than ${{\mathbf F_q}^*}^2$, and Kummer's theory tells us that necessarily $n=0,1$

(iii) If $K$ has odd characteristic $p$, radical quadratic extensions of the form $K(\sqrt a)$, with $a\in {\mathbf F_p}^*$, are classified by the image of the natural map ${\mathbf F_p}^*/{{\mathbf F_p}^*}^2\to K^*/{K^*}^2$, so in our case here, we still have $n=0,1$ over $K$

NB. Your question could also be interpreted as : for a *fixed* base field $K$, do all values of $n$ occur ? In characteristic $\neq 2$, the argument using Kummer's theory and @ still applies, but the answer obviously depends on $K$.

Comment: Yeh I think I get the case when the extension is always trivial: When char $K=2,5$ or char $K\equiv7,41,89,103  \pmod{120}$.

Comment: And 3) I think you are wrong by -1=2^2. In finite field n can only be 0,1, so is true also for all field with positive characteristic.

Comment: Concerning your comment on case 3) : no, you forget that in this specific example, char($K$) = 5, so if you take e.g. $K = \mathbf F_5$, it will contain $\sqrt -1$, so $n=1$ (without contradiction). Besides, your statement that the values of $n$ for a given $K$ must be also the values for any subfield is obviously incorrect, as shown by $K=\mathbf Q$ and e.g. $F=\mathbf Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)$. I'll add a complement to my answer to clarify/simplify the case of finite fields.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the second part of my latest answer. After "Besides...", I gave a conter example with an extension of K instead of a subfield. I 'll edit my "complements" accordingly.